# Undefined index issue on laravel google analytics

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

In my Laravel application I have implemeted laravel analytics by [Spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics) to integrate google analytics.

I had following in my controller.

```
//retrieve sessions and pageviews with yearMonth dimension since 1 year ago
      $analyticsData_Query = Analytics::performQuery(
        Period::years(1),
        'ga:sessions',
        [
            'metrics' => 'ga:bouncerate',
            'dimensions' => 'ga:yearMonth'
        ]
      );

    
    return view('bosses.home',compact('analyticsData_Query'));
```

Then in my blade I have following,

```
@foreach ($analyticsData_Query as $w)
                                {{ $w['ga:bouncerate'] }}    
                                @endforeach
```

When I print `$analyticsData_Query` array on the blade I get following

[image]

But my blade is kept showing following error (I'm trying to display the bouncerate value),

```
Undefined index: ga:bouncerate
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$w["totalsForAllResults"]["ga:bouncerate"]`?

Comment: @AdrianKokot tried, but it was just typing $w["totalsForAllResults"]["ga:bouncerate"] as a text multiple times

Comment: I'm not sure why do you use `foreach`. Isn't `$analitycsData_Query` just an object? I'd remove the foreach and just print `{{ $analitycsData_query->totalsForAllResults["ga:bouncerate"] }}`. Try and let me know what it does.

Comment: @AdrianKokot that has worked